# How to use dropna on dataframes with dtype=str?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, missing-data

When I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    

df = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=list('abc'), columns=list('DEF'), dtype=float)
df.set_value('a', 'D', 4.0)
df.set_value('b', 'E', 10.0)

     D     E   F
a  4.0   NaN NaN
b  NaN  10.0 NaN
c  NaN   NaN NaN
```

I can easily get rid of rows that only contain `NaNs` by calling:

```
df = df.dropna(how='all')
```

which yields

```
     D     E   F
a  4.0   NaN NaN
b  NaN  10.0 NaN
```

How would one do the same but on a dataframe that was initialized with `dtype=str`? The following does not work:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=list('abc'), columns=list('DEF'), dtype='str')
df2.set_value('a', 'D', 'foo')
df2.set_value('b', 'E', 'bar')

     D    E  F
a  foo    n  n
b    n  bar  n
c    n    n  n
```

Then the command

```
df2 = df2.dropna(how='all')
```

returns the unmodified dataframe.

Comment: They're not `NaN` anymore but the char `'n'` so you could just filter them out, but what is the real problem here, `NaN` is a numeric thing and `str` cannot represent it so they're not technically `NaN`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `df.replace` first, and then `df.dropna`:

```
In [1576]: df2.replace('n', np.nan).dropna(how='all')
Out[1576]: 
     D    E   F
a  foo  NaN NaN
b  NaN  bar NaN
```

This seems like the most straightforward option. From what I see, you've lost the `NaN`s once you initialise your dataframe with `dtype=str`, so this is more of a best guess replacement (you could have legitimate non-`NaN` entries that are `n` which are flagged as false positives and removed).

---

Here's a similar solution to John Galt, but keeps `NaN`s:

```
In [1584]: df2[~df2.eq('n')].dropna(how='all')
Out[1584]: 
     D    E    F
a  foo  NaN  NaN
b  NaN  bar  NaN
```

---

Expanding on Andrew L's comment, you don't need to convert to `dtype=str` to set values. You can use `.loc` based indexing instead:

```
In [1586]: df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=list('abc'), columns=list('DEF'))
      ...: df2.loc['a', 'D'] = 'foo'
      ...: df2.loc['b', 'E'] = 'bar'
      ...: 

In [1587]: df2
Out[1587]: 
     D    E   F
a  foo  NaN NaN
b  NaN  bar NaN
c  NaN  NaN NaN
```

And now,

```
In [1588]: df2.dropna(how='all')
Out[1588]: 
     D    E   F
a  foo  NaN NaN
b  NaN  bar NaN
```

Comment: Ok, that is unpleasant but a solid work around (upvoted). When I do not specify the `dtype`, I cannot use `set_value` with a string, unfortunately...

Comment: @Cleb Why not set values using `loc`? `df2.loc['a', 'D'] = 'foo'`

Comment: @AndrewL: With `loc` it indeed works but not with `set_value` which is supposed to be faster.

Comment: @Cleb Yes but the penalties from converting the `n`s to `NaN`s will be where you suffer. Do reconsider. I've added an MVCE in support of this notion.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I might just go with `loc`; was just wondering whether there is a better solution, thanks for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

They are not `NaN` any more. You could filter them like

```
In [503]: df2[~df2.eq('n').all(1)]
Out[503]:
     D    E  F
a  foo    n  n
b    n  bar  n
```

Comment: Solid workaround(upvoted); not ideal as there might be actual data around equal to `n`.

Comment: @Cleb That's a chance you'll have to take with any solution, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've converted `np.nan` to `n <class 'str'>` you can also do something like this:

```
df2[~(df2 == 'n').all(axis=1)]
     D    E  F
a  foo    n  n
b    n  bar  n
```

Obviously this is not safe if you may have real data containing "n".

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your strings with real `numpy.nan` values:

```
df2.replace('n',np.nan).dropna(how = 'all')
```

Which will work but will also change the `'n'` values in your dataframe you might want to keep. In this case drop the rows which contain only the value `'n'`:

```
df2[(df2.T != 'n').any()]
```

Moreover the second solution is computationally way more efficient:

```
%timeit df2.replace('n',np.nan).dropna(how = 'all')
985 µs ± 8.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df2[(df2.T != 'n').any()]
449 µs ± 1.33 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Same as another answer but still upvoted for the time comparison.

Comment: I initially down voted your answer because it was a ditto of mine. Now that I see you've added something more, I've removed it, but you should know that I know that it was you who revenge down voted 3 of my answers.

Comment: How could this be a revenge? I didn't know you were the one downvoting me. And even it I did, I wouldn't care. I downvoted some of your answers because they are either unefficient (use of lambda functions for instance which are basically for loops) or have side-effects (transforming data types that wasn't needed). Sorry if that hurt your feelings.

Comment: Hmm... if that was the case you'd have a lot more of your answers downvoted :) You should think thrice before downvoting, especially downvoting in anger/revenge.

Comment: I didn't understand why that would imply that more of my answers would be downvoted. Anyway, once again it wasn't out of revenge, just that your solutions weren't the best for those questions.